# jquery.switchButton on multiple pages of datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I use jQuery's Datatable plugin and jQuery's switchButton plugin, like this:

```
<table id="test-list" class="cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Enabled ?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="enable-disable" name="enable-disable" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" checked />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // format datatable
    $('#test-list').dataTable({
        "scrollCollapse":   true,
        "paging":           true,
        "info":             false,
        // other fields
        // ...
    });

    // format checkboxes as switch buttons
    $('.enable-disable').switchButton();

    // others
    // ...
});
```

The problem is: all checkboxes on the first page of the datatable are formated correctly (switch button type), but when I turn to other pages (from the second page to the end page) checkboxes are not formated (traditional type)

Comment: You have .siwtchButton on document.ready so it's applied to the elements already on the page. When you you go from one page to the next, new items are added dynamically and they never receive the switchButton(). Find a handler when the page changes and call switchButton() again.

Comment: Right, man. I added 'createdRow' handler:
    "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
        $('.enable-disable').switchButton();
    }
It works now.